# Intel graphics drivers on Xubuntu

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, fglrx

I installed the Intel's graphics drivers from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0;

After reboot, the GUI doesn't start and hangs with the text "starting version 219" on a black background.

I'm trying to install these drivers because I use the built-in GPU with a second display and I'm experiencing a terrible screen tearing effect.

My primary graphic card is an AMD Radeon 7000 series (not FGLRX). It had screen tearing too, which I solved using Compiz. The problem is that the second monitor still has this problem (with Compiz enabled).

Do these drivers work on Xubuntu 15.04 (or Ubuntu 15.04, which has the same problem)?

Could they solve the screen tearing on the second display?

Can I use both the Intel and the FGLRX drivers like I did on Windows?

Comment: Small piece of information, the hardware drivers are in the kernel, not the desktop environment (gnome, kde,xfce, etc). So we need to know what version of xubuntu which is related to the kernel.

Comment: The version is 15.04, I tried both Ubuntu and Xubuntu

Comment: How does the fglrx driver works on your system? Still having the tearing issue?

Comment: I had to reinstall Xubuntu to try fglrx. It doesn't work. It just shows a blank screen. I installed it from AMD website (downloaded deb)